# Prove $\max \{|x|,|y|\}\cdot | x/|x| - y/|y| | \leq 2|x-y|$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value, maxima-minima

Prove that:
$$\max \{|x|,|y|\} \left| \frac{x}{|x|} - \frac{y}{|y|} \right| \leq 2|x-y|$$
I tried by I didn't arrive. Please help me.

Comment: use $max(a,b)=\frac{1}{2}(|a-b|+a-b)$ and $\frac{c}{|c|}=1$ or $-1$.

Answer (score 5):

WLOG assume $|x|>|y|$, then we see that
\begin{align}
|x|\left|\frac{x}{|x|}-\frac{y}{|y|} \right| =& \left|\ x-\frac{|x|}{|y|}y\right|= \left|x-y-\frac{|x|-|y|}{|y|}y \right|\\
\leq&\ |x-y| + ||x|-|y|| \leq 2|x-y|.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer using the sign function:

Assume $|x| > |y|$ without loss of generality. Then the LHS becomes

$$\max\{|x|,|y|\}\left|\text{sign}(x)-\text{sign}(y)\right| = |x|\left|\text{sign}(x)-\text{sign}(y)\right|$$
Now, if $\text{sign}(x) = \text{sign}(y)$, then this becomes $0$ and therefore is clearly less than or equal to $2|x-y|$.

If $\text{sign}(x) = - \text{sign}(y)$, then the LHS becomes $2|x|$. However, in this case the RHS becomes
$$2|x-y| = 2|x| + 2|y|,$$
which is clearly greater than $2|x|$.

Comment: What happens when $x, y$ are vectors?

Comment: Then one needs a different approach, e.g. yours, since $\frac{x}{|x|}$ is no longer the $\text{sign}$ function. However, the OP did not specify what $x$ and $y$ belong to, and for vectors one typically uses $\|x\|$ rather than $|x|$, so I assumed $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I agree. Anyway, cute proof.