# Vector Inequality with ratio upper bound

Tags: inequality, vectors

"Let $0\neq x\neq y$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that
$$\left|\frac{x-y}{|x-y|}-\frac{x}{|x|}\right|\leq2\frac{|y|}{|x|}"$$
I can see that if it holds for $(x,y)$ then it also holds for $(rx,ry)$ for $r\neq 0$. Thus, if $|y|\geq |x|$, we can take $|x|=1$ and then it is immediate by the triangle inequality. I don't see how to treat the case where $|y|<|x|$; any ideas?

Comment: Hint: Consider the values the left hand side of the inequality can take and when they happen.

Comment: I see geometrically what's going on in the left hand side; if $y$ points in a direction "close" to $x$ then the first term is "close" to $x/|x|$ whereas if $y$ points in a direction "close" to $-x$ then $x-y$ could be "close" to being orthogonal to $x$, but this would require $y$ to have norm nearly as big as $x$. But this is all very imprecise and I don't see how to make this intuition quantitative; do you have any more advice?

Comment: I was really getting at the fact that a vector $x$ divided by its norm $|x|$ is going to have length $1$.

Comment: I see how that helps for the case $|y|\geq |x|$, but we need a more precise bound when $|y|<|x|$, right?

Answer (score 1):

Write the question as follows:
$$
\left|\frac{x-y}{|x-y|}-\frac{x}{|x|}\right|\leq2\frac{|(x-y) - x|}{|x|}
$$
Now using for any vector $z$ that $z^2 = |z|^2$, we can square and get the equivalent
 $$
2 - 2 \cos(x-y,x)\leq 4 \Big( \frac{|x-y|^2}{|x|^2} + 1 -2 \frac{|x-y|}{|x|}\cos(x-y,x) \Big) 
$$
or
$$
0\leq 2\frac{|x-y|^2}{|x|^2} + 1+ \Big( 1 - 4\frac{|x-y|}{|x|} \Big) \cos(x-y,x)  
$$
Since $1 \ge \cos(x-y,x) \ge -1$ it suffices to show that 
$$
0\leq 2\frac{|x-y|^2}{|x|^2} + 1- \Big| 1 - 4\frac{|x-y|}{|x|} \Big|
$$
Letting $w = \frac{|x-y|}{|x|} \ge 0$ we consider two cases:

1. $0.25 \ge w \ge 0$:
   $$
   0\leq 2w^2 + 1- \Big( 1 - 4w \Big) = 2w^2 + 4w
   $$
   which is evident.
2. $ w \ge 0.25$:
   $$
   0\leq 2w^2 + 1 +\Big( 1 - 4w \Big) = 2w^2 +2 -  4w = 2 (w-1)^2
   $$
   which is also evident. $\qquad \square$

Remark: we see that the inequality is tight for $w=1$ (i.e. $|x-y| = |x|$) and $1 =| \cos(x-y,x)|$, hence for $y =0$ and any $x$.

Also, the inequality is tight for $w=0$ (i.e. $|x-y| = 0$) and $1 =| \cos(x-y,x)|$, hence for  any $x$ and $y = ax$ with $a > 1$ and $a \to 1$. This case is not as obvious as the first one. Some explanation: Since $a >1$, $\frac{x-y}{|x-y|} = x \frac{1-a}{|1-a||x|} = -\frac{x}{|x|}$. Inserting this in the original inequality shows that it is tight:

$$
\left|\frac{x-y}{|x-y|}-\frac{x}{|x|}\right| = \left|-2 \frac{x}{|x|}\right| = 2 \leq 2\frac{|y|}{|x|} = 2a \frac{|x|}{|x|} {{{\tiny {\{a \to 1 \}}}\atop{\to}}\atop{{\tiny{\;}}}} 2
$$

Obviously $a >1$ is needed.

There can be no other cases where the inequality is tight, as  $1 =| \cos(x-y,x)|$ is always required.

Comment: @MartinR I answered that 3 hours ago when I wasn't aware of that source. Further, looking into the source you quote, $x$ and $y$ are not specified there to be vectors, and the proofs also do not mention that. There is a (not concluded) discussion in that source what happens in the vector case. I guess it can be generalized.

Comment: You are right, that one is not about vectors. – I'll retract the closing vote.

Answer (score 0):

In [Prove $\max \{|x|,|y|\}\cdot | x/|x| - y/|y| | \leq 2|x-y|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949744/prove-max-x-y-cdot-x-x-y-y-leq-2x-y) an estimate was shown which holds for vectors as well:

> Let $x, y \in \Bbb R^n \setminus \{ 0 \}$. Then
>   $$
> \max (\|x\|,\|y\|) \left\| \frac{x}{\|x\|} - \frac{y}{\|y\|} \right\| \leq 2\|x-y\| \, .
> $$

The proof is identical to the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1949763/42969), only with the absolute value replaced by the norm.

Applied to our problem, we have
$$
\left\|\frac{x-y}{\|x-y\|}-\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right\| \le 2 \frac{\| y \|}{\max (\|x-y\|,\|x\|)}  \le 2 \frac{\| y \|}{\|x\|} \,.
$$